# Im playing with electroluminescent paint, i want to change frequencies

Tags: power-supply, ac, frequency

I'm playing with electroluminescent paint. I can make the paint go paramagnetic and change colors by changing my power source from 240v 50Hz to 240v 1400Hz. Is there a device out there I can make or use that will create an AC voltage of 240v at 0.2-0.3A and be able to change frequency that much?

I can't design circuits but I'm capable of building them. Any assistance would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in saying that, i can do it but from 2 different devices

Comment: im interested in variable frequency so i can "Tune the paint"

Comment: You are asking for a power amplifier that can provide 240V RMS or almost 700V peak-to-peak.  With a current of 0.3 amps that is a power output of 72 watts (1200 watts for 5 amp output). This is not a trivial design and a potentially lethal device.  You could buy an audio amplifier (fed from an audio oscillator) and use it to drive a step-up transformer but you will need to exercise great care in wiring to avoid electrocution.

Comment: I believe a well selected Variable Frequency motor Drive with a big resistor as a partial load might fit the bill nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You need a signal generator that feeds an audio power amplifier, followed by a step-up transformer.

Audio power amplifiers are generally designed to put out their maximum power into a 4Ω load (or less), so at 1200W, you'll be getting somewhat over 60 Vrms. In order to convert this to 240 Vrms, you'll need a 1:4 transformer. Make sure it can handle the frequency range (and power level) that you need.